# How to detect that trigger fails after calling a stored procedure from .Net application?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

We have a .NET application (VB / VS2010) and are calling many stored procedures on a SQL Server 2008 for database queries. We also have quite a few update/insert/delete triggers that are executed automatically once these stored procedures modify the database tables.

There are quite often situations when a stored procedure is called and it seems to perform ok as no error is raised and the .NET app continues as usual. However if I then look under the covers and perform the stored procedure call manually via SQL Server Client I see that a trigger that's executed right after the stored procedure fails, thus rolling back all changes.

So my question is: what's the best way to detect and pass through errors in our .NET --> stored procedure --> trigger scenario to know for sure in the .NET app that everything succeeded or not in case of an error?

Many thanks in advance,
Steve

---

Update: I am at home now and away from my desk (and the code base) for the weekend, so won't have a chance to check the very details of the stored procedures. Thanks so much for the answers given so far. I can have a look at the code again next week.

But in the meantime...

One question was about the version of MS SQL Server: it's 2008.

From what I know out of the top of my head we are calling the stored procedures (at least those that don't read data and "just" update, delete or insert data) in this manner:

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection("connectionString")
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("EXEC STORED_PROCEDUR_ENAME), connection)
    command.Connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

I think the assumption behind the code above is the expectation that if something fails within the stored procedure or a related trigger, that

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

would then fail. That might be my first problem, i.e. will I have to alter this code?
One question below was if I use ExecuteDataReader, so the answer is no, at least not so far...

I'll comment on the SQL specific questions and suggestions below.

Comment: How are you executing the stored procedures? Are you using `ExecuteDataReader`? If so you need to read to the end of the stream to ensure you read all error messages.

Comment: Can you give an example of a trigger wher this happened and thestored proc that did the insert? It might be easier to advise you if we see how you were trying to return errors right now. And what version of SQL server? It makes a differnce in how errors are handled.

Comment: Just a thought can you use try and catch to catch sql exception in .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check @@error after each statement, and return the error if one exists.

Here's a good article for you.  Check out the section "Why is My Error Not Raised".  It describes a scenario that could be your problem.

http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-II.html

You might also want to try turning XACT_ABORT on, so stored procedures would fail for most errors.

EDIT: Here's another link that might help explain this.

http://www.novicksoftware.com/tipsandtricks/tips-erorr-handling-in-a-stored-procedure.htm

You can either return an error from your procedure if you check @@error and find it != 0, or you can use RAISERROR, which will definitely result in an exception in calling code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Comment: Newer versions of SQl Server use try catch blocks

Comment: @HLGEM: when you say that newer SQL Server versions use try catch blocks, does that refer to the RAISERROR command mentioned above? So if I use a try catch block - how would I then let my app know in case of an error that an error happened? :) I mean I could catch the error, but then I would still need to let the app know that something went wrong so I guess I would have to do it via return codes?

Comment: It refered to the fact that you no longer check @@error after each step.

Comment: The point is that you either have to propagate the error to the calling code by raising an exception within your TSQL, even if you're just reraising the same exception from a catch block, or else you can return the error itself.  Whether you figure out that an error occurred by catching it in a try/catch block, or by checking @@error, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jim and HLGEM. I'll take the error checking (however it is done) on board!

Comment: http://novicksoftware.com/tipsandtricks/tips-erorr-handling-in-a-stored-procedure.htm ***not found***

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same issue today,

to solve it i used an output @msg and placed it after each function in the sproc.

```
SET @msg = 'Test print 1'
```

each section i added one so i know what ever the last number printed was where the sproc failed. I then went to the table where the trigger was failing and adjusted it until it printed the last number and passed.

Answer (score 0):

as you mention that you are using sql server 2008. this gives capacity to use try.. catch. here is the article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Also look at this forum.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/transactsql/thread/03eae70e-d478-44a7-90f3-8e1d27d9f22e

i think try..catch will do the job. also in .net side i would use following code.

```
try
{
   // your stored procedure execution code.
}
Catch (sqlexception e)
{
  // do something with sql exception.
}
```

try this scenario see if that solves your issue.